# Do Font Files (e.g. .ttc .ttf .otf) Contain Different Weights?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I often see projects where fonts (not from a CDN like Google Fonts) will have one font file per weight. Is this always the case?

I ask because I was sent a font file from a client (Yuanti SC, a .ttc but I converted it to otf and ttf) and I can't seem to get any other weight to show other than bold.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Yuanti;
    src:  url(/fonts/yuanti.otf) format('otf'),
          url(/fonts/yuanti.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

I wanted to make sure it's not possible (or at least unlikely) that there are multiple font weights in one font file.

Comment: [TrueType Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#TrueType_Collection) (.ttc) can contain multiple fonts.

Comment: hmm... thanks. It is a big file so it must.

Comment: Note that as of OpenType 1.7, "truetype collections" no longer exist. It's just OpenType collections (https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm - "font collections" section). Real "truetype" fonts haven't existed for decades, it's been OpenType since pretty much 1995, as "OpenType fonts with truetype glyph data" which, for historical reasons, are called `.ttf` files, contrasted to "OpenType fonts with CFF glyph data", which for the same historical reasons are called `.otf` files. Both are simply OpenType fonts with the important data organised identically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> one font file per weight. Is this always the case?

Short answer: yes.

Tradition OpenType fonts (unlike the newer variable font) only cover single weights, but: don't confuse font weights with CSS weights. Fonts can technically have [any weight between 0 and 65336](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/os2.htm#wtc), and these numbers *technically* don't mean anything, they're just a way for a foundry to indicate what they feel appropriate for a full family (consisting of many differently weighted/modeled individual fonts).

In CSS, there are an artificial restriction that there are only weights 100 through 900, in increments of 100. Weight "150" doesn't mean anything in CSS, for instance, even though a *font file* can have a weight value 150 in its [OS/2 metadata table](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/os2.htm) (which, incidentally, is called OS/2 for historical reasons only).

If browsers supported font collections you could use those, but they don't: the way you load multiple weights is to literally load multiple fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(fonts/super-bold.woff) format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fonts/italic.woff) format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url(fonts/ultra-thing.woff) format("woff");
}
```

And note what happened there: it doesn't matter what the font file itself says its font weight is: *you* get to define which weight maps to which actual font resource, so if we say "in my CSS, weight 100 maps to super-bold" then the browser will do that. The CSS `@font-face` definition is what defines the mapping between the resource file and the CSS style/weight, not the font file.

Normally you'd bind 100 to ultra-light, 400 to normal, and 900 to ultra-black, but this is you calling the shots, not the fonts. CSS does not respect the OpenType metadata, the `@font-face` binding gets the final say.

As for *why* browsers don't support font collections, this has to do with which data is actually used when loading fonts. "Real" OpenType fonts (the ones you use for general purpose typesetting on your computer) come with a ton of data that is quite literally ignored when loaded as a webfont (names and contextual metadata, for instance), whereas loading a font collection would require actually parsing a lot of that data and doing resource mapping based on what is found, not just significantly complicating the matter of which packed resource maps to what, but also needing additional code to properly handle the not-even-remotely-edge cases where overrides are necessary. "What happens if someone loads a collection but they want to keep control over which sub-resource maps to which style/weight values?".

As such, adding collection support would complicate matters incredibly, without any real benefit: extracting a OpenType collection to individual ttf/otf fonts (both of which are OpenType fonts, they only differ in their glyph definitions; all the other data is identically encoded) and simply packing them for the web by using WOFF or WOFF2 is trivial, and leaves the designer/user with far more control over how to load those fonts, so it is unlikely we'll see collection support anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Anywhere I can learn more about extracting a .ttc to individual ttf/otf font files?

Comment: [The spec itself](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm) covers the layout that font collections adhere to in the "TTC Header" section so it's mostly a matter of just literally slicing up the binary file with any scripting language between consecutive header-indicated offset values. Though I'm sure people have written unpack utilities already, google should be able to find some for you.

Answer (score 3):

As nwellnhof said TrueTypeCollections can contain different fonts which can have a bearing on weight, but it can also be the way the browser renders the font which can give the impression of additional weight.

If you have photoshop you can see this by changing the ani-aliasing property across values. However some times, changing the order in which the font load can make a difference to this but it can make it worse too. Google usually gives the smoothes rendition of fonts these days.

Not really a solution as such but hopefully something I've rambled on about helps.

Comment: Note that as of OpenType 1.7, "truetype collections" no longer exist. It's just OpenType collections (https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm - "font collections" section)